# If $u,v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$, can we write $\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_\Omega (-\Delta u)v $?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $u, v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ on a **bounded Lipschitz domain** $\Omega$ (it is only Lipschitz!)

Does this hold:

$$\langle -\Delta u, v \rangle = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_\Omega (-\Delta u)v $$
where we have an actual integral on the right with the Laplacian.

The first equality is the definition of the weak Laplacian. Since $\Delta u \in L^2$ and $v \in H^1_0$, I thought we can just write it as an integral using Gelfand triple. However, this is Green's identity, for which we typically need $H^2$ for $u$.

What do you think?

Comment: Question not clear for me, what is the duality product on the left? Since $g = \Delta u$ and $v$ are in $L^2$, if this is the $L^2$ duality product then $\langle g,v\rangle = \int g v$ ...

Comment: The duality product on the left is defined as the middle quantity involving the gradients. But I also think the statement is true due to the reason that the Laplacian is in $L^2$

Comment: What is your definition of $\Delta u$? If you think about a weak definition then this is precisely the identity you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statement is true for any bounded open domain. A detail proof can be found in the Lemma 4.4 of the book [1] by Alexander Grigor’yan.

[1] *Grigor’yan, Alexander*, [**Heat kernel and analysis on manifolds**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/302888), AMS/IP Studies in Advanced Mathematics 47. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Somerville, MA: International Press (ISBN 978-0-8218-4935-4/hbk). xvii, 482 p. (2009). [ZBL1206.58008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1206.58008).